# Echo problem when a different user logs in

Tags: php, session, echo

i have been trying to change the output of my systems list or table page whenever a different user logins in.

---

i have 2 major users (admin and super admin) and minor users (company registered accounts). my admin use is to upload files sent by other company. the uploaded file is then passed to the other account "super admin". the super admin is used to approve or disapprove uploaded files submitted by the admin.this files originally came from the other company. the table is already ordered by employee name,status and title. and i already inserted the condition that it should echo the name and id once.

**This is the condition before**

when the admin logs in, the table in the home will output all the uploaded files whatever its status may be.this also applies to super admin. while in the other company, only the files uploaded by the employee in that company may be seen or is outputted.
all of this code is working properly.

**This is the condition i am expecting to have now**

when the admin logs in, the table in the home will output all the uploaded files whatever its status may be. when the super admin logs in, the homepage table will output only files with the status approved and not approved. uploaded file with a pending status must echo in the other page that i entitled "New Uploads" that i'm working to do now. And when other users log in, they will only see the files with the approved or not approved status.

i hope somehow i made it clear. :( i have been trying to solve this problem for 2 days now but wrong outputs always appear,so i would like to ask for you help :(

---

this is what the output table looks like in my system

```
if the admin page is login

*EmployeeID*     *EmployeeName*     *Title*     *FileDate*     *Status*     *Confirmation*

  20864125           Keisha          file2     Feb 01, 2000     Pending         Delete
  20080407           Mariel          file5     Aug 01, 2000     Pending         Delete
                                     file1     Jan 01, 2000     Pending         Delete
  16521253           Riorei          file13    Jan 01, 2000     Pending         Delete
                                     file10    Mar 20, 2003     Pending         Delete  

if the super admin login

*EmployeeID*     *EmployeeName*     *Title*     *FileDate*     *Status*           *Confirmation*

  20864125           Keisha          file2     Feb 01, 2000     Pending         Approve/Not Approve
  20080407           Mariel          file5     Aug 01, 2000     Pending         Approve/Not Approve
                                     file1     Jan 01, 2000     Pending         Approve/Not Approve
  16521253           Riorei          file13    Jan 01, 2000     Pending         Approve/Not Approve
                                     file10    Mar 20, 2003     Pending         Approve/Not Approve     

an if other user log in

*EmployeeID*     *EmployeeName*     *Title*     *FileDate*     *Status*           

  20864125           Keisha          file2     Feb 01, 2000     Pending
```

now that you see the difference,i would like to apply the new condition in that output :( this is the code i used

---

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                            {
                                $file_id = $row['file_id'];
                                $file_desc = $row['file_description'];
                                $file_date = $row['file_date'];
                                $file_name = $row['file_name'];
                                $file_accs = $row['folder_access'];
                                $file_employee  = $row['employee_id'];
                                $file_confir = $row['confirmation'];
                                $file_ename = ucwords($row['employee_name']);

                                $emp_id=$emp_id==$row['employee_id']?"":$row['employee_id'];
                                $emp_name=$emp_name==$row['employee_name']?"":$row['employee_name'];

                                $info = pathinfo($file_name);
                                $file_ext = $info['extension'];                                 



                                echo '<tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp; 
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="subone">
                                    <td class="sub" width="100">
                                        '.$emp_id.'
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>';
                                    if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
                                    {

                                    ?><td class="sub" width="100">
                                        <a href="" onclick = javascript:newPopup('addfile.php?emp=<?php echo $file_employee ?>');><?php echo$emp_name?></a>
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td><?php
                                    }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            echo '<td class="sub" width="182">
                                            '.$emp_name.' 
                                            <br />
                                            &nbsp;
                                            </td>';
                                        }


                                    echo'<td  class="sub" width="218">
                                        <a href="'.$file_accs.$file_name.'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;">'.$file_desc.'</a>
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td  class="sub" width="100">
                                        '.date('M d, Y',mktime(0,0,0,substr($file_date,5,2),substr($file_date,8,2),substr($file_date,0,4))).'
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td  class="sub" width="100">   
                                                '.$file_confir.'                
                                    <br />
                                            &nbsp;
                                            </td>';
                                    if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
                                    {
                                        if($file_confir == 'Pending' OR $file_confir == 'NotApproved')
                                        {                                               
                                            if(isset($_GET['id']))
                                            {
                                                $fgmembersite->Delete_Db($_GET['id']);
                                            }
                                                echo '<td  class="sub" width="100"> 
                                                <a href="index.php?id='.$file_id.'">Delete</a>
                                                <br />
                                                &nbsp;
                                                </td>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'admin')
                                        {
                                            if($file_confir == 'Pending')
                                            {   
                                                    if(isset($_GET['yes']))
                                                    {
                                                        $fgmembersite->UpdateYesDB($_GET['yes']);
                                                        //echo "<script>location.reload();</script>";
                                                    }
                                                    else if(isset($_GET['no']))
                                                    {
                                                        $fgmembersite->UpdateNoDB($_GET['no']);
                                                        //echo "<script>location.reload();</script>";
                                                    }
                                                    if (!isset($_GET['offset'])) {
                                                        $prevoffset = 0;
                                                    } else {
                                                        $prevoffset = $_GET['offset'];
                                                    }                                                       
                                                    echo'<td  class="sub" width="100">  
                                                    <a href="index.php?offset='.$prevoffset.'&searchfile='.$search.'&namelist='.$listname.'&yes='.$file_id.'">Approve</a>                                           
                                                    <br /><br />

                                                    <a href="index.php?offset='.$prevoffset.'&searchfile='.$search.'&namelist='.$listname.'&no='.$file_id.'">NotApprove</a>                                     
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    </td> ';
                                            }   
                                        }
                                    }?>
```

---

this works properly when the new condition is not yet applied.now my problem is how could i apply the new condition here? i have tried using this set of code:

```
if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] != 'sa' && $file_confir == '' OR $file_confir == 'NotApproved')
```

before the echo statement. but it produced the wrong output, can someone tell me what should i do here? :( i know i should use condition statements to do this,but i don't know which one will fit. thanks for those who would reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your if/ elseif statement checks for admin and superadmin already, wouldn't the regular user just be in the else?

```
if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa'){
    // your code here
} elseif($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'admin') {
    // more code here
} else {
    // here goes the code of your regular user
    if($file_confir == '' OR $file_confir == 'NotApproved'){
        // display the file 
    }
}
```

As a side note: You might find it a lot easier to write code / debug if you wouldn't mix HTML and PHP. The code formatting /indents are also not consistent, but that may be due to copy/paste

Comment: i am sorry if i confused you with my if-else statement but the if-else statement you noticed is for my condition of what will the link that will be displayed in the table. what i am talking about is the delete/approve and not approve links located somewhere between the if-else statement you noticed