# some item won't echo after putting some condition in php

Tags: php, html, session, echo

from this link [Echo problem when a different user logs in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6247462/749747) that i posted earlier, i managed to do or fix my problem. but somehow, there is a small error that have occurred. although my admin page is working properly, my super admin and other accounts began to output errors (although they are not really error). the employee id and employee name did not echo in the super admin page and other accounts, although the title(file uploaded),file date and status echoed.

```
//what i meant to say was, this is what the echo suppose to look like:
*EmployeeID*     *EmployeeName*     *Title*     *FileDate*     *Status*           

  20132248           Danica          file8     Jan 08, 2001     Approved          
  20896647           Jan             file7     Dec 12, 2000     NotApproved     
  20864125           Keisha          file2     Feb 01, 2000     Approved   
  16521253           Riorei          file10    Mar 20, 2003     NotApproved
                                     file3     Jul 14, 2002     Approved



//instead it echoed like this
*EmployeeID*     *EmployeeName*     *Title*     *FileDate*     *Status*           

                                     file8     Jan 08, 2001     Approved          
                                     file7     Dec 12, 2000     NotApproved     
  20864125           Keisha          file2     Feb 01, 2000     Approved   
                                     file10    Mar 20, 2003     NotApproved
                                     file3     Jul 14, 2002     Approved 

//this is the actual output that appears on my localhost
```

this is the set of codes that i think might have caused the problem,i will put a remark one which if statement the problem i think causes error

```
<?php       
                            $search = '%';
                            $fgmembersite->DBLogin();
                            $limit = 5;
                            if(isset($_GET['offset'])) {
                                $offset = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['offset']);
                            } else {
                                $offset = 0;
                            }

                            //for namelist a-z
                            $listname = '%';
                            If (isset($_GET['namelist']))
                            {                                   
                                $listname = $_GET['namelist'];
                            }

                            //for search file
                            if(isset($_POST['searchfile']))
                            {
                                $search = $_POST['searchfile'];
                            }                               
                            else if(isset($_GET['searchfile']))
                            {
                                $search = $_GET['searchfile'];
                            }

                            if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa' OR $_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'admin')
                            {                                   
                                    //$sql="select * from gmdc_employee where employee_name like '%$search%' AND employee_name like '$listname%' ";                                             
                                            $sql="SELECT `e`.* FROM `gmdc_employee` `e` JOIN `gmdc_user` `u` ON ( `u`.`company_id` = `e`.`company_id` ) WHERE (`u`.`company_name` LIKE '%$search%' OR `e`.`employee_name` LIKE '%$search%' OR `e`.`employee_id` LIKE '%$search%') AND `e`.`employee_name` LIKE '$listname%' ";
                            }
                            else
                            {                                   
                                $sql = "select `e`.* from `gmdc_user` `u`, `gmdc_employee` `e` where `u`.`username` = '".$_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()]."' and `u`.`company_id` = `e`.`company_id` AND `e`.`employee_name` like '$listname%' AND `e`.`employee_name` like '%$search%'";                                                                                                                                 
                            }

                            $query = mysql_query("$sql ORDER BY `e`.`employee_name`, `e`.`confirmation` DESC ,`e`.`file_id` DESC,`e`.`file_date` DESC  LIMIT $offset,$limit") or die ( mysql_error () );
                            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
                            $total = mysql_num_rows($result);
                            $emp_id = "";     //This will be use to remove employee_id if its already echoed.
                            $emp_name = "";   //This will be use to remove employee_name if its already echoed.


                            if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
                            {
                                $fgmembersite->HandleError("No file found.");
                                return false;
                            }
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                            {
                                $file_id = $row['file_id'];
                                $file_desc = $row['file_description'];
                                $file_date = $row['file_date'];
                                $file_name = $row['file_name'];
                                $file_accs = $row['folder_access'];
                                $file_employee  = $row['employee_id'];
                                $file_confir = $row['confirmation'];
                                $file_ename = ucwords($row['employee_name']);

                                $emp_id=$emp_id==$row['employee_id']?"":$row['employee_id'];
                                $emp_name=$emp_name==$row['employee_name']?"":$row['employee_name'];

                                $info = pathinfo($file_name);
                                $file_ext = $info['extension'];                                 

                            if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
                            {

                                echo '<tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp; 
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="subone">
                                    <td class="sub" width="100">
                                        '.$emp_id.'
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>';
                                    if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
                                    {

                                    ?><td class="sub" width="100">
                                        <a href="" onclick = javascript:newPopup('addfile.php?emp=<?php echo $file_employee ?>');><?php echo$emp_name?></a>
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td><?php
                                    }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            echo '<td class="sub" width="182">
                                            '.$emp_name.' 
                                            <br />
                                            &nbsp;
                                            </td>';
                                        }


                                    echo'<td  class="sub" width="218">
                                        <a href="'.$file_accs.$file_name.'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;">'.$file_desc.'</a>
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td  class="sub" width="100">
                                        '.date('M d, Y',mktime(0,0,0,substr($file_date,5,2),substr($file_date,8,2),substr($file_date,0,4))).'
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td  class="sub" width="100">   
                                                '.$file_confir.'                
                                    <br />
                                            &nbsp;
                                            </td>';
                                    if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
                                    {
                                        if($file_confir == 'Pending' OR $file_confir == 'NotApproved')
                                        {                                               
                                            if(isset($_GET['id']))
                                            {
                                                $fgmembersite->Delete_Db($_GET['id']);
                                            }
                                                echo '<td  class="sub" width="100"> 
                                                <a href="index.php?id='.$file_id.'">Delete</a>
                                                <br />
                                                &nbsp;
                                                </td>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    /
                                    }
//I THINK THE PROBLEM STARTS HERE
                                    else if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] != 'sa' && ($file_confir == 'Approved' || $file_confir == 'NotApproved'))
                                    {
                                        echo '<tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp; 
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="subone">
                                    <td class="sub" width="100">
                                        '.$emp_id.'
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>';
                                    if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
                                    {

                                    ?><td class="sub" width="100">
                                        <a href="" onclick = javascript:newPopup('addfile.php?emp=<?php echo $file_employee ?>');><?php echo$emp_name?></a>
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td><?php
                                    }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            echo '<td class="sub" width="182">
                                            '.$emp_name.' 
                                            <br />
                                            &nbsp;
                                            </td>';
                                        }


                                    echo'<td  class="sub" width="218">
                                        <a href="'.$file_accs.$file_name.'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;">'.$file_desc.'</a>
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td  class="sub" width="100">
                                        '.date('M d, Y',mktime(0,0,0,substr($file_date,5,2),substr($file_date,8,2),substr($file_date,0,4))).'
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td  class="sub" width="100">   
                                                '.$file_confir.'                
                                    <br />
                                            &nbsp;
                                            </td>';
                                    if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
                                    {
                                        if($file_confir == 'Pending' OR $file_confir == 'NotApproved')
                                        {                                               
                                            if(isset($_GET['id']))
                                            {
                                                $fgmembersite->Delete_Db($_GET['id']);
                                            }
                                                echo '<td  class="sub" width="100"> 
                                                <a href="index.php?id='.$file_id.'">Delete</a>
                                                <br />
                                                &nbsp;
                                                </td>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    }


                                }?>
```

i hope someone could help me figure out what caused this output. :( already spent more that an hour figuring it out. thanks for those that will reply.

MisaChan

Comment: cleaning up theses lins may help `$emp_id=$emp_id==$row['employee_id']?"":$row['employee_id'];` and `$emp_name=$emp_name==$row['employee_name']?"":$row['employee_name'];`

Comment: Have you verified that you've got the SQLs right?  The SQLs appear a little bit fishy to me.  As a side note, you should ALWAYS escape whatever you've got from user inputs before applying it to your SQLs to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone : the error is the output itself. as seen in my example above. and @shinkou : yes i already did that. that is why its output is almost correct. i think the problem revolves in this set of codes `$emp_id=$emp_id==$row['employee_id']?"":$row['employee_id'];
                                $emp_name=$emp_name==$row['employee_name']?"":$row['employee_name'];` which is the condition i used that works perfectly on other accounts.

Comment: do it like `$emp_name=($emp_name==$row['employee_name'])?"":$row['employee_name'];`

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, i did what you said but nothing changed.

Comment: try debugging the result from the query before the while loop print_r your result n see if its populated as expected.

Comment: it only printed this **Resource id #9** if i print the result, and if i print the query, only the **Resource id #8** appears

Answer (score 0):

In these 2 lines, you're effectively deleting the employee ID and name if they match those retrieved from the database:

```
$emp_id=$emp_id==$row['employee_id']?"":$row['employee_id'];
$emp_name=$emp_name==$row['employee_name']?"":$row['employee_name'];
```

I doubt if you wanted to do this instead:

```
$emp_id = ($emp_id==$row['employee_id']) ? $emp_id : $row['employee_id'];
$emp_name = ($emp_name==$row['employee_name']) ? $emp_name : $row['employee_name'];
```

Comment: i already did that but nothing happen. and this code of mine's purpose is to echo the empid and emp name once. what i mean was, if i uploaded 2 files, the last uploaded file will only have my name and id echoed and the first wont. its working properly. and im not so sure if this is really the cause. im just assuming it cause these codes changes the echo of the emp name and emp id :(

Comment: What do you mean by "if i uploaded 2 files, the last uploaded file will only have my name and id echoed and the first wont."?  Could you format what it actually looks like when you have uploaded 2 or more files with the same account?  What you gave in the question only shows 1 file per employee, which is quite confusing...

Comment: i already edited it. what i meant was, since its ordered according to name, like for example above, riorei has 2 files uploaded. since file 10 is the last upload,it will be on top, the following files uploaded by the employee riorei will not echo the name and id

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what you wanted.  Here is the guide line of what should have been done instead of overwriting the ID and name on the fly.

```
# these are used to save the previously processed entry's info
$last_emp_id = '';
$last_emp_name = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $file_id = $row['file_id'];
    $file_desc = $row['file_description'];
    $file_date = $row['file_date'];
    $file_name = $row['file_name'];
    $file_accs = $row['folder_access'];
    $file_employee  = $row['employee_id'];
    $file_confir = $row['confirmation'];
    $file_ename = ucwords($row['employee_name']);

    $file_date_formatted = date
    (
        'M d, Y'
        , mktime
        (
            0
            , 0
            , 0
            , substr($file_date, 5, 2)
            , substr($file_date, 8, 2)
            , substr($file_date, 0, 4)
        )
    );

    # begin a row
    echo '<tr>';

    if ($file_employee == $last_emp_id)
    {
        # do not display the employee's ID and name
        echo '<td>' . $file_employee . '</td><td>' . $file_ename . '</td>';
    }
    else
    {
        # display the employee's ID and name
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>';
    }

    # display other info (i.e. title, file date, and status)
    echo '<td>' . $file_accs . $file_name . '</td><td>'
        . $file_date_formatted . '</td><td>' . $file_confir . '</td';

    # end the row
    echo "</tr>\n";

    # update employee's ID and name
    $last_emp_id = $file_employee;
    $last_emp_name = $file_ename;
}
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: @shinkou : sorry if i have read your post late, what should i put inside the if else?my code is written above right? where should i put this?

Comment: @MisaChan, I've added some sample codes to indicate what should be done at where.  Please change them to suit your needs.

Comment: @shinkou : an error echo orrured again, its like, wrong echo before echoes now and the working echo before is not working or echoing properly now.

Comment: @shinkou : i tried you code and it kinda work, although there is a small problem,although sa admin page is working properly now,i noticed in the other user and superadmin that for example,if the I have 2 files uploaded,and if i accepted one,it does not echo the id and name,but once you accept the 2nd one,the topname appears.i tried to know why this happen and his is what i did.

Comment: @shinkou: i added an echo file there,i tried echoing the `$last_emp_id` and `$file_employee` (same goes with name) before the if else statement you posted.we initialized the `$last_emp_id` value to 0 right?but on the first upload of a particular name,it already contained the `$file_employee` value.i can't figure out what caused this.another is that its like since i edited the code,something is should i say destroying the page number code.what i meant to say wasi put limit to a page # 5,meaning 5 items per page,ut sometimes it echoes2,3 etc.

Comment: @shinkou: i tried to trace it as well by putting a counter.well in my hopepage in my superadmin since it contains all approve or notapproved files,(this is the actual result of my tracing)i tried accepting 4 files composed of name1 with 2 files,name2 and 3 with 1 file each.this is what happened.on my first page,only 2 files appeared,but my counter says that it looped 5times,name2 appeared on the 2nd page(solo flight!)with 5counters as well,my name3 appeared on the 3rd page with 3 loops.i dont know what caused this problems.i am trying to figure it out too.i hope that you could still help me

Comment: @MisaChan, I'm sorry that I can't help there.  I'd have to access to all your work just to figure out what's wrong.  :(  Based on your series of questions asked before, I strongly suggest that you get someone to inspect your codes.

Comment: @shinkou: i already solve it myself :) but i couldn't have done it without the help of you and stefgosselin :) here is the link if you wanna see how i solved it :) BIG THANKS! [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6287770/749747)

Comment: @MisaChan, It's good to know you have it solved.  :)  Congrats!

Comment: i too am glad to solve it @shinkou :) maybe thats because i was so down last night that i cant stop thinking on how to figure it out.some people here aren't nice and had scolded me a lot yesterday for asking :( but i sure am glad its over. encoding is my next task :P i way to relax. thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

why the line

```
if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
```

is inside block

```
else if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] != 'sa'
```

It never executes once the `else if` fails.