# don't echo correctly and error in loops

Tags: php, while-loop, echo

this is a repost,i'l make it as short as possible. :( but if you want to understand more on my problem,here is the link of my previous post: [echo problems in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6287770/749747)

my problem is,my program is producing wrong echo result:

1.most of the times it did not echo the name and id from the 1st time it was accepted.(if there are 2 files under mariel 1,and the admin accepted the 1st one(uploaded example on jan1,2010),it should echo name and id at first,then if the 2nd one was accepted(uploaded feb 2, 2010)it should echo the last file uploaded on top where the last uploaded file should have contained the name and id,then the first uploaded file must not contain the name and id,only the details(you may see link to view what it looks like). but mine did not echo at first time a person accepts the file.

2.i think there is an error in the loop.i set a limit of 5 to tell the program that it must only output 5 data per page,but mine sometimes output 3 or 1 or nothing(in random) per page.i traced it using counter and discovered it still looped 5 times although it did not echo something(meaning i/superadmin did not accept or reject any file yet)

i know this are 2 different problems,and some might be offended by that,but i believe that these 2 is somewhat related to each other.i hope someone could help me,i really cant find whats wrong with it :(

Comment: I apologize if this may seem unhelpful to you, but you need to isolate your problem. The easiest way to do this would be to just debug your code to see where it goes wrong. Have you tried something like Eclipse + Xdebug? They only take a few minutes to setup.

Comment: @Cold Hawaiian: i cant accept any since no one answered it :( one commented and said its too long. :( and when i shorten it, some asked for more to put in the echo :( its very much confusing T-T and @John : i only use notepad++,this is the project my boss gave me,even though im just having an on the job training here T-T (yes i am a student who strive to learn my errors) and @Mark Elliot:sorry if i kept on reposting it,i just dont know how to repost the last one,and i dont know if someone would still see that thats why i repost it again and then linked my old one here

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, using the question box for better formatting.

I had a look at this, copied the code and loaded it in my editor just to have a look and see.

Around line 31, you have this query:

```
$sql="SELECT `e`.* FROM `gmdc_employee` `e` 
     JOIN `gmdc_user` `u` ON ( `u`.`company_id` =  `e`.`company_id` ) 
     WHERE (`u`.`company_name` LIKE '%$search%' OR `e`.`employee_name` 
     LIKE  '%$search%' OR `e`.`employee_id` LIKE '%$search%')
     AND `e`.`employee_name` LIKE '$listname%' ";
```

Does this query return proper results when you var_dump($sql) and run that through mysql client (ie phpmyAdmin) ?

Comment: @stefgosselin: yes it does return proper results. i tried checking it in myphpadmin, wherein i used the wampserver.it gave me correct results.thus all data taken from the database is correct, but it echoes wrong output. only my _SA account_ gives correct echo result.other accounts dont

Comment: SO the problem starts on line 169, ie: `if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] != 'sa' && ($file_confir == 'Approved' || $file_confir == 'NotApproved'))` ... ? We are getting there, slowly but surely.

Comment: i thinks thats where it started. :( since that condition is if the one who log in is not **sa** it will use that condition. and since my all data in my sa works,i think somewhere in that code caused it

Comment: Ok. I will post you a tip as an answer to simplify parts of your code, first, then we can look to debug that if statement.

Comment: thanks @stefgosselin i will also try to find out more of what caused this problem :(

Comment: If you expect 5 results, and the if on line 169 filters out the five results, remove the conditions in the if to see if you get the 5 results you expect. I would start by removing the last 2 conditions, and for sure it _should_ show the 5 results.  I am not familiar with what your script is doing, but either you forgot to initialize a variable at the start of your while loop but a quick check showed they seem to be initialised ..  there is  2 variable assignments at line 230 and 231, could they be the problem? I will get back to you tomorrow, check that out.  Good-luck my friend :)

Comment: One last thing, on line 42 and 43 you have :

`$emp_id = '';     //This will be use to remove employee_id if its already echoed.
$emp_name = '';   //This will be use to remove employee_name if its already echoed.`

You realize they will always be set to "" in the first iteration of while loop,  until it reaches line 230 and 231 _on first iteration_, they are then set with $file_employee and $file_name _for the rest of the iterations_.

Comment: that code is written outside my while loop :( and if i dont put some initializations, it will cause errors

Comment: On my editor line 230 and 231 is inside the while loop, at the very outer end of it.

Comment: what i meant was the 42 and 42 lines are outside the while and the 230 and 231 is indeed inside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

These td's, on line 178 and 194 can be greatly simplified.

```
   <td class="sub" width="100">';
       //  echo $emp_id.'-'.$file_employee;
           if ($file_employee == $emp_id)
           {
               # do not display the employee's ID and name
           }
           else
           {
               # display the employee's ID and name
               echo''.$file_employee.'';
           }
               echo'
               <br />
               &nbsp;
       </td>';
```

Use this instead:

```
<td class="sub" width="100">';
    if ($file_employee != $emp_id)
    { 
        echo $file_employee;
    }
        echo'
        <br />
        &nbsp;
</td>';
```

Notice how using the ! operator simplifies the statement by more than half. Also, in my opinion you don't need a comment to say you are displaying $file_employee, it clutters your code needlessly since it is very obvious from the echo $file_employee that you are displaying it.  Clean code with good indicative variable names should be easy to read, without needing many comments.

If you need a comment to reflect on a variable displayed, better rename the variable so it is clear just by looking at it. I also removed unused commented code, the result went from `hard to understand at a quick glance` to `fairly intuitive at a glance`

My 2 cents, will post you in a few minutes on how to debug that if on line 169.

Comment: i changed and shorten my codes like the way you posted it here and tried to accept 1 file 1st in my new upload.unfortunately,it still did not echo the name and id.i tried tracing it by putting `echo $emp_id.'-'.$file_employee;` you that echo is my checker by the way :P anyway it says for example if employee_id = 1, and emp_id='', the output says 1-1 (where 1-1 is my tracer)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry for multiple answers but formatting is easier in answer box.

This line, 169:

```
if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] != 'sa' 
&& ($file_confir == 'Approved' || $file_confir == 'NotApproved'))
```

Your query returns all the results, but this if is what shows the resultset depending on these conditions.

1. Remove the conditions in the if to have only the first one left in, as so:

   ```
   if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] != 'sa')
   ```
2. Use your first td ( the empty one) to echo the results of $file_confir

   echo '
    ' . $file_confir . '

   This will indicate if there is a problem with those conditions.
3. If you *still* don't have your full expected resultset, you will know the problem is in the first condition of your clause:

   ```
   $_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] != 'sa'
   ```

My guess is the problem is problably unset values for $file_confir or a value that does not match the 2 you have in there. Only debugging and patience will tell.

Good-luck friend.

Comment: @stefgosselin: i just wanna clear out that the purpose of `($file_confir == 'Approved' || $file_confir == 'NotApproved')` is that,it tells the program that it should only output values with approved and not approved value in the file_confir :( sorry i did not tell that earlier.

Comment: It's ok, but to be clear, it seems you should have all the results of your query until you hit the if at line 169? If you expect five results, you should fix the if so it displays those five results?

Comment: how do i do that? you see i noticed this from the problems that i said that i discovered. from your 2nd post if you remember. it seems that my codes `$emp_id = $file_employee;
          $emp_name = $file_ename;` already set my $emp_name to its new value even before the 1st echo starts. remember when i said my tracer says 1-1(in the echo) where in fact,the fisrt echo should have been -1

Comment: How can it do this? I think I may have a clue as to what the problem is: are you sure you have initialised all your variables at the beginning of the while loop so they don't keep the result of the previous loop? I am too tired to re-open the editor to check, it is waaaaay past my bedtime here, but will look at it again tomorrow with fresh eyes :o)

Comment: @stefgosselin: i tried tracing it again in a paper, it produced correct result,but why doesn't it produce corrent results in the program when you run it? thus it still did not echoed 5 data in 1 page,i also tried accepting the 5 data in order and here is what i noticed, when the 1st 5 data in newupload page was accepted/rejected,the first page was empty(the echo did not move up,instead it remained in the original page) so if you accept the 1st 5 echo,its like its just removing it from echoing the table but its space still remains there

Comment: thanks @stefgosselin, il wait for your answer :) il do my best to also figure it out